# Automatically adding spaces after periods and commas, while avoiding numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is the current regex I use to sanitize sentences when people write something like:

> Hello.I'm Andres,right?

It will be automatically converted to:

> Hello. I'm Andres, right?

The problem comes up when there are numbers inside the string. Example:

> I have 40.381,32 dollars.

...will be converted to:

> I have 40. 381, 32 dollars.

My current code:

```
echo preg_replace( '/[!?,.](?![!?,.\s])/', '$0 ', 'Hello my friend.There should be a space after sentence periods and commas, but that should not apply to 40.381,32 numbers.');
```

Question: how can I avoid these rules to be applied when the **,.** characters are between numbers? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
(?<!\d)[.,!?](?!\d)
```

or

```
(?<!\d)[.,!?](?![.,!?\d])
```

Comment: Not sure PHP supports lookbehind.

Comment: @JanDvorak - But I am 100% sure that does :)

Comment: Works pretty good! (i will choose your solution as the accepted answer in about 8 minutes hehe, stackoverflow won't let me do it right now)

Comment: @JanDvorak PHP's `preg_*` functions use PCRE, which supports lookbehinds. Here's the [PHP manual on lookarounds](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php).