# Combining two preg_replace patterns into one

Tags: php, regex, string, formatting, preg-replace

Straightforward question; how can I combine the following two preg_replace patterns into one?

```
preg_replace( '/(?<!\d)[.,!?](?![.,!?\d])/', '$0 ', $filecontent);
preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $filecontent);
```

The first one comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462929/automatically-adding-spaces-after-periods-and-commas-while-avoiding-numbers), while the second simply removes excessive use of spaces.

I tried to do some what of a chain (see line commented out below), but that didn't work – also it wouldn't have been the best of solutions I guess.

```
$fp2 = fopen($filepath, 'r+');

$filecontent = file_get_contents($filepath);

$correctedpunctation = preg_replace( '/(?<!\d)[.,!?](?![.,!?\d])/', '$0 ', $filecontent);
/* $correctedspacing = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $correctedpunctation); */

/* fwrite($fp2, $correctedpunctation); */
fwrite($fp2, $correctedpunctation);
fclose($fp2);
```

I've been trying to read up on [regular expressions](http://webcheatsheet.com/php/regular_expressions.php), but I'm not familiar with using this kind of character replacement and find the patterns pretty hard to read and understand. I can't seem to add them together without breaking some or all intended function of this preg_replace. Any explanation and/or example would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If they both do completely separate things then there should be no problem keeping them separate. Just wondering why you would want to combine them. Also, you could likely add `\s` to the lookahead to prevent adding spaces where a punctuation is already followed by a space. Something like: `...(?![.,!?\d\s])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine them using:

```
preg_replace( '/(?<!\d)([.,!?])(?![.,!?\d])|\s{2,}/', '$1 ', $filecontent);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oK0eO2/1)

Comment: Thank you, and especially for that link! That site will help me a lot when learning who to work with this kind of stuff.